# What is World 0 in Super Meat Boy and how do I unlock it?

Tags: super-meat-boy

I've beaten all seven worlds and most of the dark stages and yet there's still a locked question mark before the first world. What is this world? How do I unlock it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've collected twenty bandages, you've already unlocked it. You may have gotten a message after you collected your twentieth bandage that said something like, "You have unlocked Teh Internets", "You have unlocked English", or (most recently) "You have unlocked something locked."

The locked question mark is a new zone called "Super Meat World." It's intended to be a never-ending stream of new levels for the game. An update to the game in mid-January will unlock it, along with an extremely capable level editor, and an online level sharing website. Users will be able to create new levels and upload them to be rated and played by others.

From the developer's blog:

> - Super Meat World will act as a Hub for full chapters hand picked by Team
>   Meat.
> - All chapters uploaded to Xbla after this update will be featured here.
> - Select chapters will also be uploaded to Xblas "internets" chapter
>   as well.
> - Many selected chapters will be character specific and created by
>   designers like Matt Thorson (jumper /
>   give up robot), Gaijin Games (bit.trip
>   series), Michael "Kayin" O'Reilly (I
>   wanna be the guy) and many more.
>
> But! by far the coolest aspect of
> Super Meat World is your ability to
> "Enter the Unknown". Enter the unknown is a Pc specific
> feature that grabs random user made
> levels from the level portal and
> arranges them in order of difficulty.
>
> - When Players enter the unknown they will choose what difficulty they want to play.
> - The unknown will only feature levels ranked 3+ on over all fun factor.
> - Every time you play will be a totally new set of levels, endless content.

[Here's a link to the source, with more info](http://supermeatboy.com/71/SMB_Editor_and_Portal_details_/)

Comment: Is this answer outdated?  I had Super Meat World before collecting *any* bandages.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft If you're able to access Super Meat World without any bandages, then both the answer _and_ the question are outdated.